# Hide button in recyclerview from activity with menu not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Trying to set buttons invisible in recyclerview from my activity menu options but it doesnt do anything I have created a method in the recyclerview adapter and on bindviewholder I set if statement to change visibility. The activity I setup the the way you would call a method. What am I missing? Thanks

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extendsRecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private boolean activate = false;

public PostRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Post> blogList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.postList = blogList;
}

public PostRecyclerAdapter() {

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final int itemPos = position;
    final Post post = postList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(post.getTitle());
    holder.desc.setText(post.getDesc());
    holder.category.setText(post.getTag());

    holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editClassifiedAd(post.getPostId());
        }
    });

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteClassifiedAd(post.getPostId(), itemPos);
        }
    });

    if (activate) {
        holder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public void activateButtons(boolean activate) {
    this.activate = activate;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}


PostListActivity.java
public class PostListActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

PostRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list);
    postListFrgmt();
    mAdapter = new PostRecyclerAdapter();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            if(item.isChecked()){
                // If item already checked then unchecked it
                item.setChecked(false);
                mAdapter.activateButtons(true);
            }else{
                // If item is unchecked then checked it
                item.setChecked(true);

                mAdapter.activateButtons(false);
            }

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in the method seeing if it is invoked? We need to figure out where it's failing. Set some breakpoints and examine what's going on

Comment: your recycle view is working other than showing/hiding the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostListActivity you haven't actually set the adapter to the RecyclerView.
You need to add in your recyclerview, give it a LayoutManager (linear or otherwise) and then also pass it the adapter. E.g.

```
//assuming you've declared the RecyclerView as recyclerView1
recylcerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PostListActivity.this));
recylcerView1.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

Comment: I left out postListFrgmt()  which does that do I need to do that again in the PostListActivity?

Comment: The adapter in the fragment will be different to the adapter you've declared in your PostListActivity. So the call from your menu in PostListActivity is not being received by the adapter that has been declared in your fragment. Try moving the recyclerview declaration into the activity or use an interface to pass the booleans from your menu button press to the fragment and then pass it into the fragments adapter.

Comment: That solved the problem works great now thanks a ton